# ADK Java checking if the date equal to defined date interval

Tags: java, android, date, if-statement, adk

Id like to check if current date is equal(or contains in) to some defined date interval. I have something like this:

```
        Calendar c1 =  Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

        Date lowerBound = null;
        Date upperBound = null;
        try {
            lowerBound = sdf1.parse("29-10-2013");
            upperBound = sdf1.parse("30-12-2013");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        TextView txtdate1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        if (c1.getTime().before(upperBound) && c1.getTime().after(lowerBound)) {
            txtdate1.setText("Is up to date");
        } else {
            txtdate1.setText("Is not up to date");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the functions [`before`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#before%28java.lang.Object%29) and [`after`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#after%28java.lang.Object%29) to check if your date is in a certain range.

```
    Calendar c1 =  Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

    Date lowerBound = sdf1.parse("20-10-2013");
    Date upperBound = sdf1.parse("30-12-2013");

    TextView txtdate1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    if (c1.getTime().before(upperBound) && c1.getTime().after(lowerBound)) {
        txtdate1.setText("Is up to date");
    } else {
        txtdate1.setText("Is not up to date");
    }
```

The cool thing is that you can define some functions that will checks if the data is in some defined range by creating predefined functions. See [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-check-if-date-is-within-a-certain-range-in-java/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use the string representation. Instead use the `Calendar` object to do a before and after.

```
Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();

Calendar min = \\ create your min calendar
Calendar max = \\ create your max calendar.

if ( c1.after(min) && c1.before(max) ) {
```